# inserting records from mysql table on remote database

Tags: mysql, sql, federated-storage-engine

I have two databases on two different servers, i wish to insert the records from table A on server2 to table B on server1, table A and B have identifical schema but different names.
how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use linked server in this type of scenario.....Check out following url to implement linked server

http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/querying-tables-and-views-on-a-linked-server

http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2008/tutorial/linked_servers.cfm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can try following,

- The Easiest approach as per my point is make .sql file from first server db.
- Now Open that .sql file in note and find & replace the table name A with table name B.
- Now execute that .sql file on the remote server 2.